# The radius of an interval's image through a space-filling curve

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

Take $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]^n$ a continuous tour around $[0,1]^n,$ say, some iteration of a Hilbert curve. For $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$ what is the following thing called and are there any nontrivial upper bounds?

\begin{equation}
   \max_{|a-b|<\varepsilon} \|f(a)-f(b)\|.
\end{equation}

Or if not a maximum, then the typical value for such $a,b$.

It seems that most research focuses on the opposite, more impressive direction. That is, for $\varepsilon>0$ characterizing how often  $p,q\in [0,1]^n$ have their closest tour points $f(a)\approx p,f(b)\approx q$ such that $|a-b|<\varepsilon.$

For a k-th approximation to a Hilbert curve over $[0,1]^n$ is it true that for any $\varepsilon$-length interval roughly traverses not much more than a cube of ($\mathbb{R}^n$-)volume $\varepsilon$?

Comment: [Modulus of continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Peano curve $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]^2$ is Holder continuous with exponent $1/2$ and one can have an $n$-dimensional analogue $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]^n$ which is Holder continuous with exponent $1/n$. That is $|f(a)-f(b)|\leq C|a-b|^{1/n}$ so you get the estimate
$$
\max_{|a-b|<\varepsilon} |f(a)-f(b)|\leq C\varepsilon^{1/n}.
$$
This `thing' is known as the 
[modulus of continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know anywhere these things are constructed and proven?

Comment: I do not know the reference on top of my head. Just Google: Peano curve Holder exponent.

Comment: And let's add that $1/n$ is the best exponent: any $\alpha$-Hölder curve $[0,1]\to[0,1]^n$ with $\alpha>1/n$ can't be surjective.